# Backup Postgresql with .bat in windows

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, backup

I want to create a postgresql database backup with a .bat file on Windows

I tried with this code:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
  set dow=%%i
  set month=%%j
  set day=%%k
  set year=%%l
)
set datestr=%month%_%day%_%year%
echo datestr is %datestr%

set BACKUP_FILE=odoo_%datestr%.backup
echo backup file name is %BACKUP_FILE%
SET PGPASSWORD=openpgpwd
echo on
bin\pg_dump -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U openpg -F c -b -v -f %BACKUP_FILE% formation
```

But I received nothing.

And with this code:

```
@echo off
SET PG_BIN="C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20150818\PostgreSQL\bin\pg_dump.exe"
SET PG_HOST=localhost
SET PG_PORT=5432
SET PG_DATABASE=formation
SET PG_USER=openpg
SET PG_PASSWORD=openpgpwd
SET PG_PATCH=D:\odoo
SET FECHAYHORA=%date:/=%-%time:-0,8%
SET FECHAYHORA=%FECHAYHORA::=-%
SET FECHAYHORA=%FECHAYHORA: =0%
SET PG_FILENAME=%PG_PATH%\%PG_DATABASE%-%FECHAYHORA%.sql
%PG_BIN% - i -h %PG_HOST% -p %PG_PORT% -U %PG_USER% %PG_DATABASE% > %PG_FILENAME%
```

I have the same problem.

I want to use it later in the Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? "*But I received nothing*" is not a good problem description

Comment: PG_PAT**C**H and  PG_PATH looks suspicious...

Comment: think you 
The problem is that the code does not work
Does not create a backup

Comment: think JOANOLO 
I have to replace PG_PATCH to PG_PATH 
But it creates a file zero KO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer was provided by the author:

> I think this is the solution for all:

```
@echo Backup database  %PG_PATH%%PG_FILENAME%
@echo off
SET PG_BIN="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\bin\pg_dump.exe"
SET PG_HOST=localhost
SET PG_PORT=5432
SET PG_DATABASE=motor_8
SET PG_USER=openpg
SET PG_PASSWORD=openpgpwd
SET PG_PATH=C:\OEM
SET FECHAYHORA=%date:/=%-%time:-0,8%
SET FECHAYHORA=%FECHAYHORA::=-%
SET FECHAYHORA=%FECHAYHORA: =0%
SET PG_FILENAME=%PG_PATH%\%PG_DATABASE%_%d%_%t%.sql

%PG_BIN% -h %PG_HOST% -p %PG_PORT% -U %PG_USER% %PG_DATABASE% > %PG_FILENAME%

@echo Backup Taken Complete %PG_PATH%%PG_FILENAME%
```

Comment: when I am running this script on double click on .bat file every time it is asking for password in command prompt window. How I can remove password authentication ?

Comment: I have added this "local   all    all     trust" in my pg_hba.conf file then I run my script so it will not asking for a password but creating .sql file with 0kb with no data

Answer (score 2):

It is hardly surprising that your scripts don't work, because they contain typos all over. I don't claim that I found them all, but here is a list of those that I did spot:

First script:

- There is no option `-i` for `pg_dump`.

Second script:

- There is a bogus space in `-i`, but since that option doesn't exist and will cause an error, it should be removed.
- You set `PG_PATCH` and reference `PG_PATH`.
- The environment variable `PG_PASSWORD` is not recognized by `libpq`. Remove the underscore.

You can figure out all this if you read the error messages you undoubtedly get. You should also always include such error messages in questions like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer is what you can copy the correct code

Comment: Hi 
I solve this problem and i correct the question for a new  solution


think for all

Comment: It would be better if you wrote an answer instead of editing the question. That way everybody can understand easily that it is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Laurenz Albe's code, here's how to back up an entire server using the "pg_dumpall.exe" program ([documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html)). This is for PostgreSQL 15, you may have to modify the "PG_BIN" line to match the location of your "pg_dumpall.exe" file.

```
@echo Backing up server...
@echo off
SET PG_BIN="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin\pg_dumpall.exe"
SET PG_HOST=YOUR_HOST
SET PG_PORT=YOUR_PORT
SET PG_USER=YOUR_USER
SET PG_PATH=YOUR_DESTINATION
SET PG_FILENAME=%PG_PATH%\PostgreSQL_server_back_up.sql

%PG_BIN% -h %PG_HOST% -p %PG_PORT% -U %PG_USER% > %PG_FILENAME%

@echo Backup complete. Path: %PG_PATH%%PG_FILENAME%
```

A password isn't included in the above code, you'll need to use the pgpass.conf file ([documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html)) to store the user name(s) and password(s) you'll be using.

Example file location:

C:\Users\bradl\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf

Example file contents:

```
localhost:5432:*:YOUR_ADMIN_USER:YOUR_ADMIN_PASSWORD
```